# change visibility of controls inside DataTemplate in longlistselector

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have `longlistselector` contains a `datatemplate` like `image`,`text`,and two `buttons`,
now i would like to do is,when i select `items` in longlistselector the corresponding items `buttons` will visible

Answer (score 0):

Bind Your LongListSelector with a Selected item Property and when your selection is changed that Property will be called and you can fetch which element is selected and then change the visibility of the buttons...

```
<ls:LongListSelector Margin="0,10,0,10" ItemsSource="{Binding attractionlist,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAttractionDetail,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" >
```

then make a property like this ..

```
            private ObservableCollection<AttractionDetails> _attractionlist;
            public ObservableCollection<AttractionDetails> attractionlist
            {
                get
                {
                    return _attractionlist;
                }
                set
                {
                    _attractionlist = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("attractionlist");

                   // Change visibility here
                }
            }
```

Comment: how to set selected item property